# Как перейти на community версию visual studio 2017 без переустановки?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, лицензирование

Истекла пробная версия Visual Studio 2017 Professional. Как перейти на Community версию без переустановки?

Comment: @Владимир пишет: *Истекла пробная версия Visual Studio Professional?*

Comment: А в чем проблема с переустановкой?